# GitHub API - private or forked repositories not listing nor comparing

Tags: github-api

In my GitHub account I have a few public repositories that I created plus several private repositories forked from repositories in my organization.

My problems are

a) GET /user/repos is only listing the public personally created repositories regardless of the 'type' parameter
b) COMPARE calls on the forked repositories is returning 404

I'm logging in using Oauth 2.

Is there something that I am missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the situation you're describing is as follows:

1. You belong to an organization. (Let's call it "@your-organization".)
2. @your-organization has at least one private repository. (Let's call it "your-organization/private-repo".)
3. You have a fork of that repository in your personal account (e.g., gulliver-smith/private-repo).
4. You're using an OAuth token to authenticate with the GitHub API.
5. When you access [`GET /user/repos`](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-your-repositories), the response does not include your fork (e.g., gulliver-smith/private-repo).
6. When you access [`GET /repos/gulliver-smith/private-repo/compare/:base...:head`](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#compare-two-commits), you get a `404`.

If that's right, there are a few things you'll want to verify:

1. Ensure that your OAuth token has [`repo` scope](https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/#scopes). If your token does *not* have `repo` scope, you'll observe the behavior described above. To verify the scopes associated with your token, look at the `X-OAuth-Scopes` response header.

   ```
   $ curl -I https://api.github.com/ -H "Authorization: token REDACTED" | grep ^X-OAuth-Scopes

   X-OAuth-Scopes: admin:org, admin:public_key, delete_repo, gist, notifications, repo, user
   ```
2. If you're using a token that belongs to an OAuth application, the organization may have [third-party application restrictions](https://help.github.com/articles/about-third-party-application-restrictions/) enabled. If so, you can [ask the organization's administrators to approve the OAuth application](https://help.github.com/articles/requesting-organization-approval-for-your-authorized-applications/) so that the app can access the organization's repositories on your behalf.